# Quick question regarding geocoding limits on google's API

Tags: google-maps-api

We have a google-api business license, so we can do 100k requests in a day, but at the moment, we are hitting our limits as we have a bunch of initial data to geocode. Instead of constantly hitting google, I want to set a option to turn the API off as soon as we get the QUERY_OVER_LIMIT status back. I also want to turn it back on as soon as it's available. I was going to do this by setting a timestamp in the DB the first time we get the status.

What I'm wondering is, at what time does google reset the keys so they can do more call? If it's at midnight, what timezone is it (CST/PDT/EST/GMT/etc)?

Comment: it is calculated from the first geocode with the key (it is cached by google) as soon as the ip/domain is on 100,001 the status changes. We solved this by using FME to count each api request and stores it in the db, when the count gets to 100k it pauses 24hrs. (we also slow our requests down to 0.5 a second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the time of day at which the daily quota for a service is reset varies between customers and for each API, and can change over time. Therefore there is not a sure way to know when the reset will happen. That was taken from the [Usage Limits for Google Maps API Web Services website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits). I would imagine that you can call or email them to find out more information.

The issue can also stem from too many attempts to process the API within a second. This will display the same error message. If there is a lot of traffic at a certain time that could cause the error to occur. There is a python script example on the website referenced that gives a way to check which error you could be receiving.